# Regarding to retrieve values inside the array

Tags: asp.net

Hi 
I am creating online quiz in asp.net c#. For that i have one form that displays testlist in dropdownlist & start button. After clicking 2nd form appears, 2nd form shows one label for question, radiobuttonlist for answers ,next & checkbox for review. I am creating array of random question ids in start button click event of the 1stform. when i click next button in 2nd form then next random question appears, i want array of questions those are checked for review. I used code for arrays of values ( eg.10101) 1 for true & 0 for false as follows but i want array of that question ids those are checked:

```
        int[] a = (int[])Session["values"];//this is array of random question ids created in 1st form
        int g;
        if (chkmark.Checked == true)
        {
            g = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            g = 0;
        }
        int[] chkarray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1];
        int[] temp1 = (int[])Session["arrofchk"];
        int k, no;

        if (temp1 == null)
            no = 0;
        else
            no = temp.Length;
        for (k = 0; k < no; k++)
        {
       chkarray[k] = temp1[k];
        }
        chkarray[j] = g;
```

Comment: For goodness sake, please use variable names that make sense in the future. So you want to get an array with next to it the answers that were checked for each quiz question ?

Comment: yes i want to display array of question ids that were checked for review

Comment: See a possible solution below

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would use a `Dictionary<int, bool>` for this.

In the `key` of the dictionary, you can store the random Question ID, in the `value` of the pair, you can store the checked item state. It might take you more work now to refactor it, but I believe it will save you a lot of time in the end when you want to do more actions on your quiz items.

Using a dictionary - or at least a well chosen collection, I think it will be easier to get the right data back.

For your example, it can work **only** if the positions of both arrays are the same.

```
Dictionary<int, bool> quizAnswers = new Dictionary<int, bool>(); // <questionID, checked>

// Fill dictionary with questions and answers
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  if(temp1.length > i) // Make sure we don't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException
  {
    quizAnswers.Add(a[i], temp1[i] == 1);
  }
}

// Get Answered question in array ( LINQ )
int[] checkedAnswers = (from KeyValuePair<int, bool> pair in quizAnswers
                        where pair.Value == true
                        select pair.Key).ToArray<int>();
```

The reason I am using a Dictionary here, is because I personally think it's neater than having two separate arrays.

I believe you should implement a Dictionary in your quiz, in stead of those arrays. What if the array indexes don't match, or you want to dynamically add a question to a fixed size array, etc..

It's something to take into consideration. Hope I could help you out.